# How to extract a number from a string

Tags: android, string, integer, sms

I am writting an application whereby to reset a password you will be sent an sms containing a reset code to confirm you as the owner of the account.. But am trying to build the app in such a way that it receives the broadcast of the received sms and get the specified integer only from the sms body.
Sample of the sms
*We noticed you want to reset your password. Password reset code is 3242., Thanks*

i like to get just the reset code=3242 from the whole sms body..
Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use regex as

```
  String number = body.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

Or use a regex such as `[^0-9]` to remove all non-digits as

```
String number  = body.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```